# How can I fix seeing all of my slideshow images on page loading?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I'm using this code to run my slideshow (see snippet). However, when I load my page, I quickly see all of the slides since the script doesn't work instantly. To fix it, I think I'll have to hide them using css, I just don't know how. I've used something like this before in another slideshow, this worked out there:

```
#slideshow > div ~ div{
   display: none;
}
```

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
 var i;
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
 for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
 }
 myIndex++;
 if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
 x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
 setTimeout(carousel, 5000); 
}
```

```css
 .slideshow{
  margin-top: 15px;
  z-index: 10;
 }
 
 .slide{
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div id="slideshow" name="slideshow" class="slideshow">
   <img src='{ROOT}img/Camerashop24/slide1.jpg' alt="slide-1" class="slide mySlides">
   <img src='{ROOT}img/Camerashop24/slide2.jpg' alt="slide-2" class="slide mySlides">
    <img src='{ROOT}img/Camerashop24/slide3.jpg' alt="slide-3" class="slide mySlides">
   <img src='{ROOT}img/Camerashop24/slide4.jpg' alt="slide-4" class="slide mySlides">
 </div>
```

So, how do I adjust it so that it works again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your page loads its better only first image is visible.

```
.slideshow img:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
```

This hides all images but the first one. If it has problem in some browsers, use this:

```
.slideshow img{
  display: none;
}

.slideshow img:first-child{
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#slideshow > div ~ div{
    display: none;
}
```

You are selecting `div` element which are siblings of `div` inside `#slideshow`. But there is no `div` inside it!

You likely meant `img`:

```
#slideshow > img ~ img {
    display: none;
}
```

Demo:

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 5000); 
}
```

```css
.slideshow{
    margin-top: 15px;
    z-index: 10;
}
 
.slide{
    width: 100%;
}

#slideshow > img ~ img {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow" name="slideshow" class="slideshow">
    <img src='http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/acede69a00dd92ffd13e1322d0e15d4b_large-hdwallpapers2016com.jpeg' alt="slide-1" class="slide mySlides">
    <img src='http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/city-under-construction-1080p-full-hd-wallpaper.jpg' alt="slide-2" class="slide mySlides">
    <img src='http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/ComputerDesktopWallpapersCollection540_047_inxQEjv.jpg' alt="slide-3" class="slide mySlides">
    <img src='http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/dd170f37d84b3b21635f2ece8d416afa_large.jpeg' alt="slide-4" class="slide mySlides">
</div>
```